# wp Ругается на файл functions.php

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка

Дело в том что, сейчас стоит сайт на том же самом движке, с тем же самым шаблоном , и работает всё отлично , не вылазят ошибки , не уезжает дизайн ) 
Беру шаблон , ставлю на денвере нульцевый движек, запускаю шаблон работующий, сделаный мною , уезжает блок с новостями резко в лево, сайдбары стоят на месте , если убрать файл `functions.php` то сайдбары пропадают , и новостная колонка становится на место )) 
В админке вот такое ругательство

```
eader information - headers already sent by (output started at W:\home\1.ru\www\wp-content\themes\dwar\functions.php:1) in W:\home\1.ru\www\wp-includes\option.php on line 820
```

Ругается я как понял на регистрацию виджетов, но почему ... ) что здесь не так , если на той же версии движка без ошибок все работает и ничего никуда не уезжает..
вот файл `functions.php`

```
<?php


// Регистрируем сайдбары
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'left-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="sb-bot"><div class="sb-top"> <div class="sb-right"><div class="sb-left"><div class="sb-rb"><div class="sb-lb"><div class="sb-rt"><div class="sb-lt">',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2><div class="textwidget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>'
    ));

}
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'left-2',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="sb-bot"><div class="sb-top"> <div class="sb-right"><div class="sb-left"><div class="sb-rb"><div class="sb-lb"><div class="sb-rt"><div class="sb-lt">',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2><div class="textwidget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>'
    ));

}
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'left-3',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="sb-bot"><div class="sb-top"> <div class="sb-right"><div class="sb-left"><div class="sb-rb"><div class="sb-lb"><div class="sb-rt"><div class="sb-lt">',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2><div class="textwidget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>'
    ));

}
?>
```

Очень интересно почему тот же самый код в див блоках на оригинале нормально показывает )) а скопированный уехал шаб...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробелы в начале файла убрать или кодировка не utf8 без bom

Comment: Спасибо , кодировочка спасла) просто вроде ничего не менял , ничего не делал просто слил с фтп и уже не работает)